# Manipulating data from an Oracle temporary table in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, oracle11g

I have a VB.Net application that populates an Oracle 11g global temporary table. I can see data in the temporary table *by loading it into a grid* and everything looks correct.

However, when I call an ***Oracle stored procedure*** from VB.Net that would manipulate the data in this temporary table, the stored procedure reports that my temporary table is **empty**.

I understood that data in an Oracle global temporary table should be visible to all sessions so I'm not sure why this is happening and what the solution would be.

Please advise.

Regards,
M. R.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong, my understanding is that the data is session specific so it won't be visible to other sessions.

Another similar thing that can sometimes be confusing is that unless the table has been created with `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`, then it'll clear it self out when you commit.